# Swift [Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have been trying to change the content in an array called testArray in the class Collabs and then save it back to the parse server.

```
@IBAction func addToArray(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var objectToSave: PFObject?

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Collabs")
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: collabID) { (object, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else if let content = object {

            objectToSave = content
        }

        if objectToSave != nil {

            objectToSave!["testArray"] = ["foo","bar","foobar"]

            objectToSave!.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR")
                } else {
                    print("SUCCESS")
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

I've seen quite a few posts that talk about access rights however, to the best of my knowledge, the class Collabs has public read and write enabled

Comment: Put your code that starts with line `if objectToSave != nil {` inside the if else statement and it will work...

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your suggestion and got the same error. I'd be happy to post my code trying your response if you would like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I didnt check it that deeply before, try this

```
    var objectToSave: PFObject?

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Collabs")
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: collabID) { (object, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let content = object {
                objectToSave = content
            }
            if objectToSave != nil {

                objectToSave!["testArray"] = ["foo","bar","foobar"]

                objectToSave!.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("ERROR")
                    } else {
                        print("SUCCESS")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mazel Tov, it turns out I ran into trouble with the access rights I mentioned. The trick was to enter:                                                                let acl = PFACL()
        
        acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
        acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
        
        user.acl = acl
During Sign up (I apologize for formatting)

Comment: im getting the same error im new to swift and ios development where should i do the acl authentication?